# How do I implement a dynamic role in Plone 3?

Tags: plone

I want to allow access to certain content to certain users for a limited time,
using a 'Dynamic Role' in Plone 3 ( http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security/dynamic_roles.html ).

To this end I've created an add-on with a copy paste of example code - except that for now getDummyRolesOnContext() always returns my role.

But Plone never calls, or instanciates my DummyLocalRoleAdapter, and obviously my users never get the role assigned.

Here's what I know so far:

- My dynamic role is defined in a rolemap.xml and get's created upon add-on installation.
- My add-on is being imported - an exception on it's first line prevents Zope from starting
- None of DummyLocalRoleAdapter are being called - I've spiked all of them with warnings and exceptions.
- The adapter does get registered.

How do I continue debugging this - what's the magic part I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you need to somehow activate borg.localprole PAS plug-in in acl_users:

https://github.com/plone/borg.localrole/blob/master/borg/localrole/utils.py

There might have been borg.localrole add-on installer entry in the past, but now there doesn't seem to be one. My guess is that you need to call the actions from borg.localrole add-on setup code manually in your own add-on.

acl_users when borg.localroles is correctly installed:

[image: acl_users when borg.localroles is active]

Comment: That's just what my acl_users looks like - though I'll give reinstallation a try.

Comment: Try putting pdb breakpoint in borg.localroles.workspace and step through it to see 1) if it gets your adapter at all 2) if it in fact reads it then why it is lost https://github.com/plone/borg.localrole/blob/master/borg/localrole/workspace.py#L476

Comment: Breakpoint doesn't trigger.- where do I get the portal to pass to setup_localrole_plugin()?